# Как получить URL текущей страницы

Tags: java, vaadin

Не поолучается получить адрес текущей страницы на вадике, нагуглить не получилось нагуглить .. вообще это странно, т.к. эта вещ должна легко делаться...

Comment: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/1072883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getApplication().getContext().getBaseDirectory().getPath();
```